# Bought two games from Steam while abroad

Tags: steam

I live in Ireland but currently in Hong Kong. I bought Farcry 3 and Dishonored today on Steam and I'm wondering if it will work when I'm back in Ireland?

When I was purchasing both games I just changed the billing address to the one I'm currently at in Hong Kong and it worked, the currency displayed are in dollars and not euros and there was no warning messages. I'm asking this question as I'm afraid those games could be region locked when I get back to Ireland and I end up wasting my money.

Answer (score 7):

Unless there was a specific issue with a game you purchased in Hong Kong [being banned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_banned_video_games) in Ireland, you should have no issues playing the games you purchased.. no matter where you go.

Issues come up when you install and use Steam on a different computer (authorizing that computer), although this is not a numbers game ([steam doesn't limit the number of computers](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8963-EIKC-3767)).  This issue isn't common, but it has happened on rare occasions.

Issues also come up if you haven't changed/fixed your billing address on the credit card you use for a purchase, but that's not so much a Steam problem as it is a problem with not keeping up with your own addresses.

So... feel confident that you'll have no problem continuing to play Far Cry 3 and Dishonored when you are back in Ireland.

Comment: Actually, once purchased, all games work everywhere. I tested this in Germany (where my Steam-Account address is), South-Africa and Turkey.

Comment: @Bora *Actually* there aren't any Banned games in Turkey or South Africa... so your testing actually didn't test anything.

Comment: There are banned games in Germany (Quake and Quake 2). I could buy and install these games in Turkey and South-Africa, which I couldn't have in Germany (they are not even listen on Steam). It's the same story.

Comment: @Bora Yes, but *DID* you purchase and install them in Turkey, and does Steam still give you the option to play them once you are back in Germany... in the Library menu of Steam itself?

Comment: Yes they all worked, in Germany and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to receive gifts of censored games, which are not available in your country. I live in Germany and got a friend in Austria who sometimes did this favor for me. In referation to your question you should not have problems with the location when you bought the games already.